# Как обеспечить устойчивость соединения Access - ODBC - MySql

Tags: sql, база-данных, access, ms-access, odbc

Соединение Access - ODBC - MySql
К Access подключены таблицы из MySql.
Всё работает нормально..

Как только в файле не происходит активность более 1мин., таблицы сбрасываются, либо ошибки - "#Имя?" во всех ячейках

Чтобы подключить заново, нужно (по обстановке):
  1. Обновить таблицы через "диспетчер связанных таблиц"
или
  2. Закрыть, открыть форму.
или
  3. Закрыть, открыть файл.

**Вопрос**
Как сделать чтобы один раз подключил и "забыл"?
А не дёргаться с обновлениями…

Comment: Открыть, прочесть всё нужное в буфер, и сразу закрыть.

Comment: В свойствах соединения указать keep-alive.

Comment: @Akina Не могу найти эту настройку. Не могли бы вы подсказать где она находится?

Comment: @Akina Подключение  выполняю по следующей инструкции см. скрин. http://prntscr.com/e6lwfo

Comment: Осталось нажать кнопочку **Details >>** и прочитать подпись к третьему флажку на вкладке "Connection".